# python pandas translate DF but got another Error

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I want to use pandas to translate my CSV file by DF. Before this time , my CSV files are four files,not one. So this time I combine with four files and delete som columns,after this ,I use my code to translate . But got an error.

My data:

```
count    birdName      date        location    time              
  15       bird1     1990-02-10    balabala   0900:1200        
  10       bird2     1990-02-10    balabala   0900:1200      
  20       bird3     1990-02-10    balabala   0900:1200      
  40       bird4     1990-02-28    balabala   1300:1500      
  10       bird5     1990-02-28    balabala   1300:1500       
  25       bird6     1990-02-28    balabala   1300:1500        
  45       bird7     1990-03-01    balabala   0900-1200      
  15       bird8     1990-03-01    balabala   0900-1200       
  30       bird9     1990-03-01    balabala   0900-1200  
  ...       ...         ...        ...          ...
```

The format I want :

```
date            time     location  birdName count birdName count birdName  count                     
1990-02-10   0900:1200   balabala    bird1    15    bird2    10    bird3    20                   
1990-02-28   1300:1500   balabala    bird4    40    bird5    10    bird6    25       
1990-03-01   0900-1200   balabala    bird7    45    bird8    15    bird9    30                       
  ...          ...         ...        ...    ...     ...     ...    ...    ...
```

With my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('./birds.csv')

common = ['date','time']
grouped = df.groupby(common)
df['idx'] = grouped.cumcount() 
df2 = df.set_index(['idx']+common+['location'])
df2 = df2.unstack('idx')
df2 = df2.swaplevel(0, 1, axis=1)
df2 = df2.sortlevel(axis=1)
df2.columns = df2.columns.droplevel(0)
df2 = df2.reset_index()
df2.to_csv('./birdsIwant.csv')
```

But got an error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\python27\allentest\birdsIwant .py", line 9, in <module>
df2 = df2.unstack('idx')
......
File "D:\python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape.py", line 206, in   
get_new_values
new_values = np.empty(result_shape, dtype=dtype)
MemoryError
```

My csv file link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6SUWnrBmDwSQ0p3NlRLR0FXWjA&authuser=0

Can somebody teach me how to solve? Thanks

Comment: I just ran your code on your 9 lines of data and it seemed to work fine.  Maybe a data issue outside of those first 9 lines?

Comment: That's not impossible. When the csv file still 4 files,it no error . This error appears after I combined 4 csv files.